# "Failed to transform class with name [CLASS NAME]. Reason: javax.servlet.ServletContext" when running tests in an ANT script

Tags: java, ant, junit, powermock

I get an initialization error in the logs when I try to run a particular suite of tests after running my ANT test tasks. The full stack trace is as follows:

```
Failed to transform class with name [CLASS NAME]. Reason: javax.servlet.ServletContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name [CLASS NAME]. Reason: javax.servlet.ServletContext
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:266)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:635)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:269)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3168)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3127)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.validate(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:108)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:70)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:42)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:156)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:40)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:244)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:61)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:450)
at javassist.bytecode.Descriptor.toCtClass(Descriptor.java:592)
at javassist.bytecode.Descriptor.getReturnType(Descriptor.java:489)
at javassist.CtBehavior.getReturnType0(CtBehavior.java:306)
at javassist.CtMethod.getReturnType(CtMethod.java:217)
at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.modifyMethod(MainMockTransformer.java:163)
at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.allowMockingOfStaticAndFinalAndNativeMethods(MainMockTransformer.java:133)
at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.transform(MainMockTransformer.java:65)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:251)
```

The problem started when I added the following to the start of the test suite:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({problemClass.class, classBeingTested.class})
```

With the goal being when the class being tested attempts to instantiate the problemClass, it'll just create a mock object instead of a real instance.

The classBeingTested extends the class that's mentioned in the stack trade. i.e. classBeingTested extends [CLASS NAME].

I am also spying on the implementation of classBeingTested, so that another method does nothing when called rather than being called.

I'm not sure if prehaps there is some kind of interference where it's not ok to both prepare the class for a test and insert the mocked constructor in there **as well as** spy on it?

---

NOTE: I can run the tests fine in IntelliJ using either run/debug. In both cases the test completes and is shown as passing. So it's only when the ANT build occurs that it fails.